# Foreach loop logs ones constant input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, foreach

I have two logs in a foreach loop. One outputs the current element of the loop, and the other logs "1". The elements all get logged, but the "1" gets logged ones. I use Debug.Log for logging. I execute the script in a unity project.
The loop looks therefore something like this

```
foreach(CostumeClass A in B)
{
    Debug.Log("1");
    Debug.Log(A);
}
```

The Output is

```
>1
>FirstElement
>SecondElement
>...
```

I expected

```
>1
>FirstElement
>1
>SecondElement
>...
```

Comment: Hard to believe. Can you post [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It looks "something like this" or exactly like this? If you're re-writing this code as an example you might have done it differently without noticing it. You should put your actual loop code in there. You can omit or change sensitive info, but include all flow control like ifs and fors that are present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intentional behavior in the Unity console that can manually be toggled on or off by using the `Collapse` button. When collapsing is on, the console will only display the first instance of recurring error messages, and increment a number for each recurring.

> Also, unity only does this within loops. If you just write Debug.Log("!") four times, it'll appear four times... still don't really understand this.

This is because the messages are identical since they're called from the same location while in a loop, but different when you call them four times in different locations of your code.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, Unity console packs identical logs together into one log and then writes on the right how often they appeared.

This just cost me one hour of my life, thanks unity.
[image]

Comment: Also, unity only does this within loops. If you just write Debug.Log("!") four times, it'll appear four times... still don't really understand this.